# App getting network issue on latest android real device

Tags: android

In my app I am asking user to access below permission on runtime

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

at my Activity file I used **Easypermission library** to enable runtime permission

My app shows user current location after launch. Getting user permission fetch user contact list and then store into firebase database. see device1 pic 
[image]

Note : Device1 android version : 5.1.1

But fetching problem on another device. where application not getting internet. show as device2 below pic

[image]

Note : Device2 android version is 9. Except this app all are working fine on device2

I don't get any clue where is the problem. both device are connected on same wifi.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the Google maps SDK loaded properly. Most of the times issues in the maps sdk only

Comment: checked, it seems ok

Comment: @m-s-t share your code snippet !

Comment: @RajeshRajendiran added

Answer (score 0):

code is fine except you are fetching location and move camera to current location if internet is connected. see your condition :

```
   if(Connectivity.isConnected(this)) { }
```

if device doesn't have internet connection it will not proceed inside loop.